Add a className property to a custom Framer Motion component in React
I am new to Framer Motion. I saw on their site that in order to add a class to a custom element, I had to create an override:
import type { ComponentType, FC } from "react";

export function withClass(Component: FC): ComponentType {
    return (props) => {
        props.className += " test";
        return <Component {...props} />;
    };
}

The problem is that TypeScript doesn't like props.className and shows me the error Property 'className' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
I want to apply className="typewriter" to the custom component MotionTypeWriter.
Here is the parent component 'Home':
import './Home.scss';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import TypeWriter from '../../effects/TypeWriter/Index';

export default function Home(){
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const trPath = "pages.home."; // translation path

    const MotionTypeWriter = motion.create(TypeWriter);

    return ( 
        <main id="home">
            <section className="home_section">
                <h1>{t(`${trPath}title`)}</h1>
                <p className="subtitle">{t(`${trPath}subtitle`)}</p>

                <MotionTypeWriter 
                    className="typewriter"
                    text={t(`${trPath}text`)}
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    transition={{ duration: .3 }} 
                />
            </section>
        </main>
    );
}

I tried with props: any (as well as other types), but then the following error 'Type { className: string; text: never; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined; text?: string | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; } & MotionProps'.
